# Display block inside a table

Tags: css, html-table

Images usually have a gap below them. To avoid that, I give them `display:block` but if I do that in a table, the image goes to the left.

How to have the image in the center and with no gap below it?

(I use inline CSS because I use it in a mail)

I have it here to play: https://jsfiddle.net/rc6jzvx2/

```
<table style="margin:0 auto; width:80%;">
<tr>
    <td style="background-color:gray">
    <img style="display:block; margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center;" src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_128.png">
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean the image usually has a line behind?

Comment: What do you mean with line behind? I can't see any after changing your `jsFiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/rc6jzvx2/1/

Comment: Sorry, I mean a line below. If you remove display block there is a small space below. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/rc6jzvx2/11/

Comment: what is wrong with the question? Why the negative point? What should I improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the gap below the image and center it by setting the vertical-align property of the image to top and setting the text align to center on the table cell, not the image:

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
td {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_128.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works, but I do not understand why vertical-align: top ?

Comment: @Nrc images are rendered inline and leave a gap for descender text elements that hang below the line, like the letters j, y, and p. Adding the vertical align adjust the positioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `margin:0 auto` instead of `text-align` to center the image. It works fine with `display:block`:

```
<table style="margin:0 auto; width:80%;">
<tr>
    <td style="background-color:gray">
    <img style="display:block; margin:0; padding:0; margin:0 auto;" src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_128.png">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you missed the </tr>

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="margin:0 auto; width:80%;">
<tr>
    <table style="margin:0 auto; width:80%;">
<tr>
    <td >
<div style="background-color:gray;text-align:center">
    <img style="" src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_128.png">
</div>
    </td>
</table>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

If you use it for a mail, as I just read, then it is fine to use the inline-styles.

**SOLUTION:**

You can just use `display: block` and `margin: 0 auto;` in your image for it to center in its container.

You can create a class which you can later on keep using when you need the same style for different images:

```
.img-center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also, I recommend you remove your inline-styles and add them in an external css file for separation of concerns and reusability.

---

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/twzss3cL/)

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.my-table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
.img-center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.bg-gray {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<table class="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td class="bg-gray">
      <img class="img-center" src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_128.png">
    </td>
</table>
```